# Authentication when i am a guest

Tags: php, laravel

I made a few middleware for User, Organizer and Admin. It work but when I try go in from guest I have some errors.

My ask is how I can include guest to my code.

Thanks

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (\Auth::user()->function== 'Organizer' or \Auth::user()->function== 'Admin' or \Auth::user()->function== 'User')  {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/')->with('status','My message');
}
```

> Trying to get property 'function' of non-object

is my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `auth()->guest()` to check if the user is logged in:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $allowedUserTypes = ['Organizer', 'Admin', 'User'];

    if (auth()->guest()) {
        return redirect('/')->with('status', 'My message');
    }

    if (in_array(auth()->user()->function, $allowedUserTypes))  {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/')->with('status', 'My message');
}
```